# Android: Selecting theme color from preferences

Tags: android, eclipse

I wish to set the color pressed item of navigation drawer of my app through preferences but I can't seem to find a way to do so. I have created a list in my preferences with hex color codes as values and I have no idea how to use the values in my java class. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:
First define your new colors in colors.xml in values like this:

```
<color name="my_blue">#4FC3F7</color>
<color name="my_yellow">#FDD835</color>
```

Then, you define a new theme like this (my_theme.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyRandomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_blue</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/my_blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Then, look at how I change the color dynamically:

My layout:

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Blue"
    android:id="@+id/btnBlue"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="#162c69" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Yellow"
    android:id="@+id/btnYellow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="#9b8a09" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mix"
    android:id="@+id/btnMix"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#920f08" />
```

My activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    this.setTheme(R.style.MyRandomTheme);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Change theme to yellow
    Button yellowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnYellow);
    yellowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_yellow));
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_yellow));
            }
        }
    });

    //Change theme to blue
    Button blueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
    blueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_blue));
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_blue));
            }
        }
    });

    //Change theme to mixture of blue and yellow
    Button mixButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMix);
    mixButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_blue));
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_yellow));
            }
        }
    });
```

}

The result:

[image: result]

Also for reading from preferences and writing to preferences try this:

```
        //Write to preferences
        String s = "this is a test.";
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("A", s);
        editor.apply();
        //Fetch from preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs2 = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(prefs2 != null) {
            String text2 = prefs.getString("A","");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This is the string: "+text2);
        }
```

You can pass your parameters like "R.color.my_yellow" and have it in your preferences till your user change it. I hope it helps. Let me know if you have any question.