# Notification bar solid to transparent

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I wonder if there's any way I can make some sort of transition between fragments in a ViewPager where my notification bar goes from transparent to solid color and the second view (that we're moving to) goes up to notification bar and not the top edge of the screen? Right now it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: A simple workaround is to hide the Notification Bar

Comment: yes, simple, but not what I want. Already tried it

Comment: [Then here is what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551234/android-selecting-theme-color-from-preferences/34072723#34072723)

Answer (score 0):

This is what is stated in the manifest for example:

```
<activity android:name=".view.TuActivity" 
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

This is what would go in styles:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, please post your answers on the [main StackOverflow page in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) so that it may be of more use to others. [Hay un sitio web en español aquí.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)